# How to launch GNU PSPP's GUI?

Tags: debian, gnu

The [homepage of GNU PSPP](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) shows the following screenshot:

[image: PSPP GUI]

I tried installing it with the following command on Debian:

```
$ sudo apt install pspp
```

However, when I now run the command `pspp`, I see the following:

```
PSPP is free software and you are welcome to distribute copies of it
under certain conditions; type "show copying." to see the conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY for PSPP; type "show warranty." for details.
GNU pspp 1.4.1
PSPP>
```

Where is the GUI and how can I launch it on Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSPP itself is a console program. There exist different GUI wrappers, of which I believe [psppire](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/psppire.1.html) to be the best known.

`apt install psppire` should do the trick.

It is also referenced on the GNU pages for PSPP [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/tour.html#gui)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, `psppire` is not available in Debian repositories: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=psppire

Comment: Have you tried if it is already included? Maybe you can already run `ppspire` ?

Comment: You are right. I can't believe I was this stupid.